ISO 8601 Duration, mix week and date, time?
This is part of the RFC 5545 specification, which is based on the ISO 8601:
   Format Definition:  This value type is defined by the following
      notation:

       dur-value  = (["+"] / "-") "P" (dur-date / dur-time / dur-week)

       dur-date   = dur-day [dur-time]
       dur-time   = "T" (dur-hour / dur-minute / dur-second)
       dur-week   = 1*DIGIT "W"
       dur-hour   = 1*DIGIT "H" [dur-minute]
       dur-minute = 1*DIGIT "M" [dur-second]
       dur-second = 1*DIGIT "S"
       dur-day    = 1*DIGIT "D"


I do not quite understand the dur-value formatting. I think that the / stand for an or right? That means that you should not be able to mix dur-date, dur-time and dur-week?
If that is the case then the chaining of dur-date = dur-day [dur-time] actually permits the use of dur-date and dur-time in the same duration value, but forbids that dur-week is mixed with anything else.
So this P1W1D duration value would be invalid?

Note about it is based. it is set explicitly as a kind of subset of ISO 8601, and done for calendars.  In your case, it would just be P8D. On other RFC you see that there may be also some changes vs ISO 8601, e.g. the sign of -00:00, to distinguish when the information about timezone was not available (compatibility with older standard and protocols)  vs. UTC. So if you do not have ISO 8601, do not consider such things as ISO 8601 compatible, just inspired

Yes. Otherwise it should have read:
  dur-week   = 1*DIGIT "W" [dur-date]

or perhaps:
  dur-week   = 1*DIGIT "W" ([dur-date] / [dur-time])


Yeah that's what I thought, but shouldn't that be a validation error on iCalendar.org? This also parses fine with python.
